# keyboard overlay textinput iOS

Tags: ios, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have registration form and has 7 text area fields in it.
When I have click on bottom text area, keyboard overcomes the text area and user is not able to see what he/she has entered.

I am using flash-builder 4.7 and air sdk is 13.0

What to do to overcome this issue? I have tried with soft keyboard, but it seems is not working for iOS.

Comment: Take a look this just apply this class in to you project https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: you are ignoring the fact that he is using FB 4.7 and AIR. Obviously Objective-C does not apply unless he's writing ANE

Answer (score 0):

First you could set your myappname-app.xml node :

```
<softKeyboardBehavior>pan</softKeyboardBehavior>
```

to automatically pan.

By code you can listen to these events (on the stage) and move your content accordingly:

```
SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_ACTIVATE
SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEACTIVATE
```